Data Imputation and Cluster Analysis
Is there a preferred method of imputation for cluster analysis?  Would the selection of imputation method be different if it were dbscan versus hierarchical clustering?
It seems there is an ongoing debate as to what the "best" imputation method is.  My particular inclination is that random forest or MICE based on random forest is the most accurate.  However are there preferred methods of imputation when performing a cluster analysis.  Note that the missing data involves binary and numeric (int / float) variables.
